# Should non-uniformly updated live regions use the ARIA busy attribute?

Tags: accessibility

I am facing an issue while testing for accessibility.

I have used `role="alert"` for an error message [single level]. Do I need to use `aria-busy="true"` / `aria-atomic="true"` / `aria-live="polite"`

```
<td><span role="alert" class="error-msg-show"></span></td>
```

I have already defined `role="alert" but do I need to use any other ARIA attributes?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here but it looks like a question about implementation (specifically: coding) rather than UX. Have you tried asking this on http://stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: Hi @AndrewMartin, up to my analysis and understanding, if we are using html5 tag role="alert" then we don't need to use any of ARIA tag for highlighting dynamic updates.

Comment: This still sounds like implementation to me.

Comment: Accessibility implementation issues tend to be considered in-scope because they are so closely tied to UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`role="alert"` *should* be all you need (it has an inherent live region behaviour) although I suspect best practice is to also include `aria-live="polite"` to ensure the widest possible support.